# OpenGL ES 2.0 Render to texture coordinate system

Tags: opengl-es

I find if I use `glFramebufferTexture2D` to render primitives to a texture in the OpenGL ES 2.0, the Coordinate System is not the same as when rendering to the default framebuffer. E.g.: V0(-1,-1), I think will be at left bottom, but if I render to a texture, V0 will be at the right top. Can somebody tell me why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(-1, -1) should certainly not map to the top right. But it can appear to be the top left, depending on how you look at the data.

In reality, (-1, -1) is always the bottom left in the default OpenGL coordinate system. The reason it can look confusing is because of the way textures are arranged in memory. They are stored bottom to top, i.e. the first row in memory is the bottom most row. This is different from most image file formats, where the first row is the top most row. This is the root cause for most y-inversion issues.

A couple of scenarios where this can cause unexpected behavior:

1. You load an image from a file with a format that stores data top to bottom, and use it for sampling. If you want to display the image in the original orientation, you need to use 1.0 for the v texture coordinate corresponding to the bottom vertices, and 0.0 for the top vertices, which is the opposite direction you use for the vertex coordinates. Using 0.0 for the top texture coordinate will put the first row of the texture at the top, which matches the order in memory.
2. You do a `glReadPixels()` with default settings. The rows of the image in the result are ordered bottom to top. If you want to save the data to an image format that stores data top to bottom, you need to flip the order of the rows while writing out the data.
3. You render to a texture using an FBO, and then use this texture for sampling. This texture has the rows arranged bottom to top. The v texture coordinates are now flipped compared to what you used in example 1, where the texture data was arranged top to bottom.

Comment: Oh,thank you,This problem has troubled me for a long time, but now I seem to already know how the problem,so,thank you very very much! @Reto Koradi